# Как правильно работать с ошибкой Docker-a "Error while fetching server API version"?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Новичок в Docker. Пытаюсь запустить на Docker-e сборку такого full-stack проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Автоматизация сборки проекта настроена и работает по следующему принципу:

1. npm-таск `"Incremental development build"` запускает компиляцию `EntryPoint-FrontEnd.ts` и `EntryPoint-Backend.ts`; выходные JavaScript-файлы помещаются в `01-DevelopmentBuild`.
2. npm-таск `"Run server"` запускает откомпилированный скрипт `EntryPoint-Backend.js`, причём при изменении этого файла скрипт будет перезапущен.

Если в терминале появится сообщение `Приложение стартовало, порт XXX доступен для прослушки.`, значит всё прошло успешно. На всякий случай приведу листинг `EntryPoint-Backend.ts`:

```
import Express, {
  Application as ExpressApplication
} from "express";
import RequestBodyParser from "body-parser";

import authenticationRoutes from "./Routes/AuthenticationRoutes";


(function executeApplication(): void {

  const expressApplication: ExpressApplication = Express()
      .use(RequestBodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
      .use(RequestBodyParser.json());

  const DEFAULT_PORT: number = 5000;
  const port: number = typeof process.env.port === "undefined" ? DEFAULT_PORT : Number(process.env.port);

  expressApplication.use("/api/auth", authenticationRoutes);

  expressApplication.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Приложение стартовало, порт ${port} доступен для прослушки.`);
  });
})();
```

Без Docker-а всё работает прекрасно, но следующим шагом в данном проекте будет добавление базы данных без её локальной установки на компьютер. Тут и понадобится Docker, но и `EntryPoint-Backend.ts` тоже нужно будет запустить в контейнере (во всяком случае, нужно уметь это делать).

Я видел самые разные настройки Docker, но поскольку большую их часть я не понимаю, то начал с такого минимального `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  logic:
    image: node:12.4
    command: npm run 'Incremental development build' && npm run 'Run server'
    volumes:
      - ./01-DevelopmentBuild:/Application
```

- В будущем в этот же файл я добавлю сервис базы данных; судя по всему обойтись без лишних `Dockerfile` возможно и прописать всё нужное в `docker-compose.yaml` возможно.
- Если Вы хотите раскритиковать использование Volum-ов, то альтернативные решения приветствуются, при этом:

  1. Работа таска `"Run server"`, **автоматически** перезапускающего Node.js при обновлении `EntryPoint-Backend.ts`, не должна нарушаться (в режиме локальной разработки). Другими словами, после запуска `docker-compose up` никаких перезапусков или пересозданий вручную через консоль быть не должно.
  2. В контейнере не должно быть ничего лишнего, в частности `.ts`-файлов и всех файлов под `node_modules` на картинке выше.
- В настройке отсутствует указание портов. Насколько я видел, если не указать порт, то Docker не упадёт, потому отложил указание портов на потом (но Вы можете их указать в решении).

Ошибка при запуске `docker-compose up` возникает такая:

```
D:\IntelliJ IDEA\InHouseDevelopment\ProjectsForFunctionalTesting\FullStackWebApplication-NodeJS>docker-compose up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1244, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 966, in send
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 32, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 72, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 59, in connect
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'Specified file not found')

[48560] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Ошибка `Specified file not found` - это я перевёл автоматически локализованное сообщение на английский; оригинал сообщения не английском и не на русском. В остальном ничего не понятно; большая часть сообщений об ошибке - какие-то пути к `.py`-файлам, которые неизвестно какое отношение к моему проекту имеют. О каком файле вообще идёт речь в `(2, 'CreateFile'`?

Но поскольку за разъяснением каждой ошибки я бегать на StackOverflow не буду, то основной вопрос у меня такой: как правильно работать с подобными ошибками? Где искать подсказки, указывающие на причину и потенциальные решения?

Comment: Ошибка не связана с кодом вашего приложения, это ошибка docker-compose или docker. `какие-то пути к .py-файлам, которые неизвестно какое отношение к моему проекту имеют` - по этой же причине. давайте посмотрим что не работает. 1) `docker run -it --rm node:12.4 node --version` - работает? 2) сделайте минималистичный файл - замените в `docker-compose.yaml` команду на `command: npm --version` и удалите все остальное, должно остаться `image` и `command`, ну и все что выше по иерархии. потом запустите `docker-compose up` - выскакивает все та же ошибка?

Comment: @TotalPusher, Благодарю Вас за желание помочь! 1) - всё работает. 2) - отработал и вывел `fullstackwebapplication-nodejs_logic_1 exited with code 0`.

Comment: @TotalPusher, теперь у меня другая ошибка... Похоже что ошибка NodeJS. Это уже претендует на другой вопрос, но прежде чем я его задам, я должен насколько возможно самостоятельно исследовать новую ошибку.

Comment: Странно, 2 - не должно было запуститься. Потому что это ошибка программы docker-compose. Я 2 пункт добавил чтобы вообще показать как проблемы решать - сделать минимальную воспроизводимую ошибку. Потом отлаживать - работа с логами, предположения и их проверка. Следующее что бы я хотел спросить - про версии обоих. Потому что может быть конфликт совместимости. А 1 пункт - проверка что вообще докер работает.

Comment: Поскольку я в этом просил именно показать мне, как работать с данной ошибкой, то Ваш комментарий - это отличный ответ на вопрос. Пожалуйста, оформите его, чтобы я мог Вам дать очки репутации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Программа `docker-compose` [написана на питоне](https://github.com/docker/compose), а сам docker - [на go](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce). Поэтому непонятные ошибки типа `File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py"` связаны с самой программой.

Как решать такие проблемы:

1. Проверяем сам докер: выполняем `docker run -it --rm node:12.4 node --version` или более [стандартную проверку **Hello world**](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/) `docker run -it --rm hello-world` - исключаем сам докер
2. Делаем минимальный тест для проверки `docker-compose` и запускаем через `docker-compose up`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  logic:
    image: node:12.4
    command: npm --version
```

Этот тест 100% рабочий, поэтому, если нет проблем с `docker-compose`, он должен пройти.

Вообще, ошибки `docker-compose` мало информативные, в ошибках только стек вызовов. Я попробовал искать по  [сорцам](https://github.com/docker/compose) `File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version` - нет ни файла `client.py`, ни `_retrieve_server_version`. Почему не нашел - не знаю, может быть у вас более старая версия. Если бы нашел, то по исходному коду можно было бы понять, что не так.

С какими ошибками я сталкивался:

- не запущен докер-демон, проверяется через `sudo service dockerd status` (для винды аналогичную команду я не знаю) - я сильно подозревал именно это
- повреждены файлы на диске - это была самая трудно диагностируемая ошибка для меня, определил я ее путем сравнивания md5-хешей файла докера и аналогичного из дистрибутива (`md5sum /usr/bin/docker`). Ошибка была в docker, хотя казалось, что виноват docker-compose, он выдавал также стек вызовов
- не совместимы версии программ docker и docker-compose - эти программы ставятся отдельно друг от друга, начните с проверки версии docker - не сильно ли она устарела